# Raw Input - Convertir de C++ a C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows-forms

Estoy tratando de usar **Raw Input** siguiendo esta documentación: [Using Raw Input:
Performing a Standard Read of Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input#performing-a-standard-read-of-raw-input)

Y quisiera que me ayuden a convertir esta parte del código, que está en C++, a C#:

```
UINT dwSize;

GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
if (lpb == NULL) 
{
return 0;
} 

if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != dwSize)
         OutputDebugString (TEXT("GetRawInputData does not return correct size !\n")); 

RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

/*Código no relevante para la pregunta...*/

delete[] lpb; 
return 0;
```

Las funciones y 'structures' ya las hice y estan bien.

Comment: Aquí no ayudamos porque no tenemos nada mejor que hacer. Así que sube tu progreso y te ayudaremos con lo que falte.

Comment: Eso es lo que me falta. Lo demas está correcto.

Comment: Lectura recomendada para aprender a [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré adaptarlo en C#

```
int WM_INPUT = 0x00FF;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)      //evento sobreescrito de la ventana 
    {

        if (m.Msg == WM_INPUT)      //mensaje Raw input
        {
            RAWINPUT miRaw;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUT));

            int outSize = GetRawInputData(
                m.LParam,
                uiCommand.RID_INPUT,
                out miRaw,
                ref size,
                Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));

            if (outSize != -1)      //si no hay ningun error 
            {
                if (miRaw.Header.Type == RawInputType.Mouse)   //dispositivo tipo mouse
                {
                    label1.Text = miRaw.Mouse.ButtonFlags.ToString();   //uso simple
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Más información: [pinvoke.net - estructuras Raw Input](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.RAWINPUT)